# Running the stress utility causes CPU to drop to lowest frequency

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cpu, cpufreq

When running idle, I see the CPU frequencies running at maximum. When I run the `stress` utility on all available cores, I see the CPU frequency drop down to 800 MHz.

HP ProLiant DL360 Gen10 Plus server with a 3rd Generation Intel® Xeon® Scalable Processors

Running Ubuntu 22.04, with Max Performance BIOS settings

I've only ever seen something like this before with a Dell tablet that had extremly low thermal thresholds in the CPU, never in a server product.

Comment: Check the temperature... if higher than the max allowed  it can slow down the CPU, and the fan speeds...